# ASP.NET project .dll not overwritten in bin folder on server when publishing

Tags: asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2019, publish

Whenever I publish an ASP.NET webapplication to my hosting server, the existing project .dll in the bin folder on the server is not getting updated. It only works when I delete the existing .dll from the bin folder on the server beforehand.

Can I override any settings for this to get VS2019 publishing and overwriting the project .dll any time I publish my project, so that changes in code behind are always incorporated during the Publish?

I have to mention that the bin folder is grayed out in de project tree, so it is not set to Include In Project. Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Got it already. I set the bin folder to Include In Project and now the project .dll is getting updated on the server when I publish my project.

So it is an option to set only the project .dll to Include In Project. That would mean that it is not necessary to copy the whole bin directory tree to the server every time.